# MSVC 14: std::type_info unavailable when building without exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2015, rtti

I'm using MSVC 19.0.23506.0 and building without exceptions:

- Definition _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0
- Exception handling was removed through CMake:

  `string(REGEX REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")`

  Which means the CXX flags are the following:

  `/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /W4 /MP`

The following minimal example is enough to reproduce my error:

```
#include <typeinfo>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::type_info* ptr = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the example above leads to the following error:

```
main.cpp(6): error C2039: 'type_info': is not a member of 'std'
```

Why MSVC disables the support for type_ids when exceptions are disabled although the usage of RTTI is enabled through the `/GR` flag.
(Seems like it replaces the whole `vcruntime_typeinfo.h` header to remove the type_info definition).

Comment: Interesting comment: "The option _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 is undocumented, untested, and unsupported by Microsoft". Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/

Comment: It works when I omit _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 but several libraries I'm using test for this definition (`googletest` and `cppformat` for example). Does it mean that it is nearly impossible to disable exception usage in MSVC?

Comment: Unlikely that MS will do anything about it. [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811347/compiling-vc-12-0-with-has-exceptions-0-and-including-concrt-h-causes-a-compiler-error) is another bug report closed as `by design` with the note: `Macro _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 is undocumented and unsupported by Microsoft`.